# System.String is consuming too much heap memory

Tags: java, string, memory-leaks, apache-poi, heap-memory

Consider the below code in any method.

`count += new String(text.getBytes()).length()`

I am facing memory issue.

I am using this to count number of characters in file. When I am fetching heap dump I am getting huge amount of memory occupied by String Objects. Is it because of this line of code? I am just looking for suggestions.

Comment: what is the size of `text`?  Actually what is `text`?

Comment: Consider it a string. Basically calling readAll method of openCSV library which returns String array and I am iterating on each string to convert it into UTF-8 string using new String(text..., StandardCharset(UTF-8), then finally getting a count.

Comment: If you just want to count some length, why do you create a new String from a byte[]?

Comment: Actually characters in Strings can be of different languages, so converting to UTF-8 is important, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `text` is a `String` this code is roughly equivalent to `count +=text.length()`. The difference are mostly:

- it needlessly requires more memory (and CPU time) by basically encoding the code in the platform default encoding and decoding it again
- if the platform default encoding can't represent any specific characters in `text`, then those will be replaced with a `?`. If those characters aren't in the BMP then this can actually result in a decreased length.

So it's arguably strictly worse than just taking the `length()` of text (if the second thing is actually intentional, then there's more efficient ways to check for that).

Apart from that, the major problem is probably the size of the content of `text`: if it's a whole file or some other huge junk of data, then keeping it all in memory instead of processing it as a stream will always produce some memory pressure. You "just" increased it with this code, but the fundamental solution is to not keep the whole thing in memory in the first place (which is possible more often than not).

Comment: Ok. Understood. Can you please let me know what could be the optimal way of doing this without creating memory pressure?

Comment: @ShivanshNema: if by "this" you mean the code you posted in your question, then my answer already contains the best replacement. If you want an answer to your more general problem of handling all data at once, then I can't give a specific answer without specifics of your code. Please post a new question, if you want a more general solution.